# SQL to get the 2nd (nth) record for each group (postgresql or mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I googled and stackoverflowed high and low and not able to find any concrete solutions to show the 2nd (nth) record for each group.

Consider the following table (order by created_at desc):

```
----------------------------------------------
bid_id | status    | created_at
----------------------------------------------
1      | cancelled | 2015-10-03 
1      | awarded   | 2015-10-02
1      | pending   | 2015-10-01
2      | pending   | 2015-10-01
3      | denied    | 2015-10-02
3      | pending   | 2015-10-01
```

The result output should look like this (grouped by bid_id):

```
bid_id | status    | created_at
----------------------------------------------
1      | awarded   | 2014-10-02
3      | pending   | 2014-10-01
```

What is an efficient SQL to achieve this? Any tips are greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think you should decide which RDBMS you want this to be about.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `row_number` to assign row numbers in each `bi_id` partition ordered by `created_at` column. Then you can simply select the 2nd or whichever row you need. This works in `postgres` as it supports `window` functions.

```
select bid_id, status, created_at
from
(
select bid_id, status, created_at,
row_number() over(partition by bid_id order by created_at desc) as rn
from tablename
) x
where x.rn = 2;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response -- and the `partition` stuff is new to me, thanks! This worked so I will give this an accepted answer.